# How to make the text on bootstrap carousel stay, while the images move?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Basically, I got the carousel working, but I just want the image to transition but the text to be the same on each slide. Ideally the text wouldn't move, but the images would in the background.

Comment: Post the code you have tried (jsfiddle too)

Comment: Are you looking for the text to be on top of the image or above/below it?

Comment: On top of the image, with the images moving in the background!

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example: http://www.bootply.com/pINPxqzlJ2

Use an `absolute` position an overlay element that you place before the `carousel`...

```
.overlay { 
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:12;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Place a `<div>` outside of the carousel items and use the `style=''` to position it where over the carousel you want.

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
     <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" >
                  <!-- items -->
        </div>
</div>
    <!-- text div -->
<div id = 'text' style='position:absolute; top:0; right:0;'>Hello, this goes in top right corner of screen over carousel</div>
```

Comment: If you place this div inside the carousel-inner, but still in a div separate from your "item" divs, then the overlaid text will move nicely with the content as the browser is resized.