# How to make the text on React Bootstrap 4 Carousel stay, while the images move?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

Basically this is the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23791186/4120196), but for the [React Bootstrap Carousel component](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/).

So I have a working carousel but I want a text to be on top of it, that doesn't move while the images change.

This is my working `Carousel` code snippet - as you can see I added my overlay text at the bottom of the loop. It does stay on top, just like I want, but it also adds an additional empty carousel item, which I don't want. (I tried making this work in js-fiddle and codesandbox.io but I'm not smart enough...)

```
import React from "react";
import Carousel from "react-bootstrap/Carousel";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let carouselImgs = [
    {
      title: "Test1",
      img: "https://images.app.goo.gl/FrGs95rzsNfc6YkW8"
    },
    {
      title: "Test2",
      img: "https://images.app.goo.gl/tPkFSMH796PmV3pq9"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <Carousel className="App" interval={3000}>
      {carouselImgs.map(carouselImg => (
        <Carousel.Item
          key={carouselImg.title}
          className="oneness-container mb-2"
        >
          <img src={carouselImg.img} className="img-fluid rounded-lg" alt="" />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <div className="bottom-center">
              <h3 className="rounded px-2 py-1 d-inline">
                {carouselImg.title}
              </h3>
            </div>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
      ))}
      {<h1 className="overlay">Overlay title</h1>}
    </Carousel>
  );
}
```

CSS of `.overlay`:

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

I like the comment on [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23791289/4120196) - that says to this:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
     <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" >
                  <!-- items -->
        </div>
</div>
```

> ...place [the overlay div] inside the `carousel-inner`, but still in a div separate from your "item" divs...

But unfortunately I don't know how to get inside the `carousel-inner` since the React Bootstrap component doesn't show it like that.

Comment: Try using codesandbox.io instead of jsFiddle

Comment: @user992731 thanks, worked much better than jsFiddle, but I didn't figure out how to get the CSS working - see my updated question

Comment: Your sandbox doesn’t run

Comment: @user992731 thanks for the heads up - when I clicked it again, it worked, but some code was missing. So I'm giving up on codesandbox.io - also this is inside a GatsbyJS project so I tried the GatsbyJS template - but it didn't even update any of my code changes :(

Comment: Are just trying to duplicate this ( https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/pINPxqzlJ2 ) but use the bootstrap react component?

Comment: @user992731 yes

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @user992731 no, I still have no idea how to do it with these react-bootstrap tags